# CATIA V5 Teardrop bubble 3D Model

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, catia

In CATIA V5 I am having difficulties transforming my 2D sketch into a 3d model, I have attempted to use the Multi-sections solid tool but if im honest i am struggling to grasp how to use it. Can anyone assist please? Please see picture of the sketch.

[image: 2D Sketches]

Comment: It’s in the title so thought it was quite clear, im going to add it anyway

Comment: Thanks Rob, I attempted to create a tag but I don’t have enough points to create one.

Comment: Look at "surface" modeling